# Maven Could not resolve dependencies for project, Failure to find snapshot in Nexus

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus

I am having problems doing a build using :

mvn clean -U install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

The artefact is not in nexus, but was created in my local repository.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mis-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project x.y.z:mis-core:ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
    Failure to find x.y.z:mis-core-api:jar:tests:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in https://company.net:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The -U parameter forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories. Since there isn't an Artifact in Nexus, remove the forced check.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the headsup, but tried it without the -U update and got the following: Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly . It might be a network proxy issue.

Comment: Likely this:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465088  ... but I can't say for sure since  you haven't included the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed by the support team white listing my machine and using corporate wifi.